why it´s not returning who has access into the file?
So i have full control over a sharepoint in a site, i want to retrieve for each file, who has access control to it by name, but when i do it, it always gives back none
from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential

# Authentication credentials
username = "x"
password = "x"
site_url = "https://x.sharepoint.com/sites/cognitive.automation/"
root_folder_url = "/sites/cognitive.automation/Documentos%20Partilhados"

# Authenticate and create the client context
credentials = UserCredential(username, password)
ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(credentials)

def get_permissions(item):
    item.expand(["RoleAssignments", "RoleAssignments.Member", "RoleAssignments.RoleDefinitionBindings"]).get().execute_query()
    
    roles = []
    for role_assignment in item.role_assignments:
        member_name = role_assignment.member.login_name
        roles.append({
            'Member': member_name,
            'Roles': [role_def.name for role_def in role_assignment.role_definition_bindings]
        })
    return roles

def process_folder(folder):
    folder.expand(["Files", "Folders"]).get().execute_query()
    
    # Process files in the current folder
    for file in folder.files:
        file_url = file.properties["ServerRelativeUrl"]
        # Retrieve the ListItem associated with the file
        list_item = file.listItemAllFields.get().execute_query()
        permissions = get_permissions(list_item)
        print(f"File: {file_url}")
        for perm in permissions:
            print(f"    Member: {perm['Member']}, Roles: {', '.join(perm['Roles'])}")
    
    # Recursively process subfolders
    for subfolder in folder.folders:
        process_folder(subfolder)

# Get the root folder and start processing from there
root_folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(root_folder_url).get().execute_query()
process_folder(root_folder)```


